# C# IDbConnection FbConnection failed. Index out of range

Tags: c#, connection, firebird, interbase

I want to connect to Interbase Server in my local network using c# and Firebird client. I tried a lot of different examples, but everything failed. Finally I found this page http://www.mono-project.com/Firebird_Interbase, so I based my code on this example.

When I call this function, it returns the error:

```
Index is out of Range... (via MessageBox.Show(e.Message);)
```

I know, that the whole code is not clean, but I wanted to post the complete class, I fix the other errors later.

```cs
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Configuration;
using FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient;

namespace IBcon
{
    class interbase
    {
        public DataGridView testbla()
        {
            string connectionString =
            "Database=C:\\data\\DB.GDB;" +
            "User=SYSDBA;" + "Password=masterkey;" +
            "Dialect=3;" + "Server=192.168.1.15";

            IDbConnection dbcon = new  (connectionString);
            DataGridView dgv = new DataGridView();
            try
            {
                dbcon.Open();  <-- Error!
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
                return dgv;
            }
            IDbCommand dbcmd = dbcon.CreateCommand();
            string sql = "SELECT * FROM TABLE";
            dbcmd.CommandText = sql;
            IDataReader reader = dbcmd.ExecuteReader();

            dgv.DataSource = reader;
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable("TABLE");
            ds.Tables.Add(dt);
            ds.Load(reader, LoadOption.PreserveChanges, ds.Tables[0]);
            dgv.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];

            // clean up 
            reader.Close();
            reader = null;
            dbcmd.Dispose();
            dbcmd = null;
            dbcon.Close();
            dbcon = null;


            return dgv;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: As far as I know FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient only works with Firebird, not with Interbase. I'd also suggest that you post the entire stacktrace, not just the exception message.

Comment: use fdb as extension of the DB. Does this help?

Comment: @magicandre1981 The extension doesn't matter (and that would give a different error if it was the wrong database name). There are still a lot of companies that use `gdb` as the extension for Firebird databases.

Answer (score 3):

`FirebirdClient` will not work with InterBase. It's for Firebird. You need to use ADO.NET provider for InterBase.

Comment: ok, first of all, thank you all. I installed ADO.NET and tryed a the code (.net 4.5 / c# / VS2012) like this: http://goo.gl/zzc0XG 

But every time I start the program, it crashed with the error, that GDS32.DLL was not found. I installed ADO at my Win7  32bit system and add the DLL to my references.

Comment: Looks like you don't have `GDS32.DLL` (comes with InterBase) near your app (somewhere where system looks for DLLs when asked to load).

Comment: I have installed the IBConsole, which require the GDS32.DLL. The DLL file exists in C:\Windows\System32 dir. I googled a lot and find many websites saying I have to register the DLL file (regsvr32 || regsvr /i). Every time I try this an error occurred (the module failed to loaded... dllregisterserver).

I'm so sorry to ask all that simple stuff. I tried to fix this errors by my own (google etc), but everything I tried failed.

Comment: You don't have to register it. Just place it whenever the application tries to load from (default paths, predefined paths, ...).